# Run a loop with 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This code allows me to run a loop with two arrays:

```
$string = $Downloads->datei;
$paths = explode(';', $string);
$string2 = $Downloads->dateiname;
$filename = explode(';', $string2);

foreach (array_combine($paths, $filename) as $path => $file) {
    $Inhalt .= '<div class="DLB_Download_Zeile">
                    <a href="'.$path.'" target="_blank">
                        <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Bild"><img src="fileadmin/media/images/pdficon.png" width="30" alt="PDF Icon"></div>
                        <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Link">'.$file.'</div>
                    </a>
                </div>';    
}
```

Question: How would the code look if I had another array?

Comment: are they of equal length?

Comment: Another array of what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you are using arrays of equal length the most simple solution probably woud be a normal for instead of a foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they of length are equal

```
 <?php
  $paths = ['path1', 'path2'];
  $filenames = ['file1', 'file2'];
  $another = ['another1', 'another2'];

  for ($x = 0; $x < count($paths); $x++) {
    $all[$x]['path'] = $paths[$x];
    $all[$x]['filename'] = $filenames[x];
    $all[$x]['another'] = $another[$x];
  }

  foreach ($all as $row) {
    $Inhalt .= '<div class="DLB_Download_Zeile">
                <a href="'.$row['path'].'" target="_blank">
                    <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Bild"><img src="fileadmin/media/images/pdficon.png" width="30" alt="'.$row['another'].'"></div>
                    <div class="DLB_Download_Zeile_Link">'.$row['filename'].'</div>
                </a>
            </div>';  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)